# How do I buy a house in Morthal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I can't find the steward In Morthal and the Jarl won't send me on quests.

I have Hearthfire and a house in Whiterun and Falkreath. I am thane in both.

Do I have to be thane in Morthal as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try talking to the Steward during business hours (8AM-8PM). He should be in the halls or somewhere in Morthal. Yes, **you must be a Thane in Morthal** in order to purchase a house.

If this does not help, [here](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/hearthfire/189716-why-cant-i-get-land-morthal.html) is a link that describes something similar to your problem.

Comment: @bubblyGaming18 You're very welcome! An easy way to pass time is to use the wait feature. Enjoy your new piece of land :)

Comment: I always use wait but I just always came at night idk why

Comment: @bubblyGaming18 no worries :)